# How to get camera brightness from Vuforia?

Tags: ios, objective-c, vuforia, brightness, luminance

I'm using Vuforia SDK for AR. I need to get the luminance from the device camera. I searched on Vuforia forum but couldn't find anything there. How can I get the camera light intensity from Vuforia SDK?

Answer (score 1):

Vuforia supplies the [Advanced Camera API](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/Advanced-Camera-API) for getting camera properties, but it is only supported in Android.

As far as I know, in iOS you do not need it and you can do it directly using the iOS APIs - as you can see in [this post](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/ios/advanced-camera-api)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've solved my issue. Vuforia 7 has introduced Illuminating class that has a method to get light intensity.